# F() expression not working with foreign key comparison when None

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to compare Foreign Keys across a join via F() expression. The QuerySet I've built returns expected results, except when one of ForeignKey's values is None.

I'm writing a simple PTO Requesting system. All PTORequests have a profile (the person taking the request) and an approver (assigned at creation, the person who is tasked with approving the request). All profiles have a "manager" who they report to. My goal is to query all PTORequests where the approver *is not* the profile's manager.

```py
class PTORequest(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='pto_requests')
    approver = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='employee_pto_requests')

class Profile(models.Model):
    manager = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="reports")
```

My query is:

```py
PTORequest.objects.exclude(approver=F("profile__manager"))
```

It should be simple enough, but the results are confusing.

```py
>>>pto = PTORequest.create(profile=profile_1, approver=profile_2)
>>>profile_1.manager = profile_3
>>>profile_1.save()
>>>PTORequest.objects.exclude(approver=F("profile__manager")) # returns 'pto', as expected
<QuerySet [<PTORequest: 1>]>
>>>profile_1.manager = None
>>>profile_1.save()
>>>PTORequest.objects.exclude(approver=F("profile__manager")) # returns empty queryset, unexpected
<QuerySet []>
```

When setting the manager to None, and the PTORequest's approver to profile_3, the manager *is different* than the approver, but is not returned in the queryset. Am I misunderstanding something about F() expressions or foreign keys?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that the `approver` is `None` and the `profile__manager` is `None` too because you've removed the relation. Then the exclude condition is `True` and that is why the queryset value is `[ ]`.

If you don't want to exclude `None` foreign keys you can do:
`.exclude(approver__isnull=False, F("profile__manager"))`

Comment: I appreciate the contribution but the approver is not None in this scenario, as described here:
```pto = PTORequest.create(profile=profile_1, approver=profile_2)
```